# Yutsis graphs in quantum theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics

Cubic Yutsis graphs appear in the context of the quantum theory of angular momenta. The recognition of these graphs is [NP-complete](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X08001297).

Is there any implication to quantum physics if recognition of Yutsis graphs can be done in polynomial time? Is there any insight from quantum mechanics into why recognizing such graphs must be intractable?